# How to move files in Linux based on its name in a folder with a corresponding name?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would need to move a series of files in certain folders via scripts. The files are of the format `xxxx.date.0000` and I have to move them to a folder whose name is the same value given.

For example:

- file hello.20190131.0000
- in folder 20190131

The ideal would be to be able to create folders even before moving files but it is not a priority because I can create them by hand. I managed to get the value of dates on video with

```
 ls * .0000 | awk -F. '{Print $ 2}'
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: You can do more than print $2 in awk. How about printing a command for bash?

Comment: That's a [useless use of `ls`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#ls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial awk command provided much of the answer. You just need to do something with the directory name you extract:

A simple option:

```
ls *.0000 | awk -F. '{printf "mkdir -p '%s'; mv '%s' '%s';",$2,$0,$2}' | sh
```

This might be more efficient with a large number of files:

```
ls *.0000 | awk -F. '{print $2}' |\
sort | uniq |\
while read dir; do
    mkdir -p "$dir"
    mv *."$dir".0000 "$dir"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
ls *.0000 |\
  sort |\
    while read f; do
      foldername="`echo $f | cut -d. -f2`"
      echo mkdir +p "$foldername/"
      echo mv "$f" "$foldername/"
    done
```

i.e.: For eache of your files, I build the folder name using the `cut` command with a dot as field separator, and getting the second field (the date in this case); then I create that folder with `mkdir -p` (the `-p` flag avoids any warning if the folder should exist already), and finally I move the file to the brand new folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with **rename**, a.k.a. Perl rename.

Try it on a **COPY** of your files in a temporary directory.

If you use `-p` parameter, it will make any necessary directories for you automatically. If you use `--dry-run` parameter, you can see what it would do without actually doing anything.

```
rename --dry-run -p 'my @X=split /\./;  $_=$X[1] . "/" . $_'   hello*
```

**Sample Output**

```
'hello.20190131.0000' would be renamed to '20190131/hello.20190131.0000'
'hello.20190137.0000' would be renamed to '20190137/hello.20190137.0000'
```

All you need to know is that it passes you the current name of the file in a variable called `$_` and it expects you to change that to return the new filename you would like.

So, I split the current name into elements of an array `X[]` with the dot (period) as the separator:

```
my @X = split /\./
```

That gives me the output directory in `$X[1]`. Now I can set the new filename I want by putting the new directory, a slash and the old filename into `$_`:

```
$_=$X[1] . "/" . $_
```

---

You could also try this, shorter version:

```
rename --dry-run -p 's/.*\.(\d+)\..*/$1\/$_/' hello*
```

---

- On ArchLinux, the package you would use is called `perl-rename`.
- On debian, it is called `rename`
- On macOS, use **homebrew** like this: `brew install rename`