# How can I extract files from multiple folders and rename according to folder name (bash)?

Tags: linux, bash, directory, rename, subdirectory

I have a folder A, which has folders B1, B2,B3, etc. Each folder contains log.txt file. What i want to do (using bash) is extract all log.txt files to folder A and rename them as B1.txt, B2.txt, B3.txt, etc. How can i do this?

I tried the script below, but got error: dr = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

import shutil
import os
import sys

dr = sys.argv[1]

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dr):
for file in files:
if file == "log.txt":
spl = root.split("/"); newname = spl[-1]; sup = ("/").join(spl[:-1])
shutil.move(root+"/"+file, sup+"/"+newname+".txt"); shutil.rmtree(root)

Comment: Have a look at `rename` https://stackoverflow.com/a/54462292/2836621

Comment: Have already tried, did not work

Comment: Ok, please click [edit] and show what you have tried and how/why it failed. Thank you.

Comment: @lemontree Your script is python, but you're asking for a bash solution. That's fine. But to be clear, my solution is a bash shell script.

Comment: The posting of your code is hard to read. We don't see where one code line ends and the next one starts. Please format it properly.

Comment: `dr = sys.argv[1]` is not a valid bash command. What are you doing here exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd A || exit 1
for i in B*/; do
    i=${i%/}
    [[ -f "$i"/log.txt ]] &&
    mv "$i"/log.txt "$i".txt
done
```

There's also `B+([0-9])/` (instead of `B*`) to specifically match one or more digits in the directory name. Requires `shopt -s extglob` first.

Answer (score 0):

A for loop over B... directories should get it done
*Assuming `A` directory is adjacent to B ...*

#### test

```bash
# try run

for file in B{1,2,3}/*.txt; do
    echo $file A/${file%/*}.txt;
done
```

#### sample output

```bash
B1/log.txt A/B1.txt
B2/log.txt A/B2.txt
B3/log.txt A/B3.txt
```

#### run

```bash
# safe-run
# cp not mv, not lose your files

for file in B{1,2,3}/*.txt; do
    cp $file A/${file%/*}.txt;
done
```

Comment: Nice, works fine if you have not to many B folders to list!